# STEPPER MOTOR CONTROLLER Using LEONARDO PRO MICRO

Tags: motor, arduino-leonardo, arduino-pro-micro

I want to Use LEONARDO PRO MICRO and A4988 Stepper Motor DRIVER to control Nema 17 Stepper Motor.

[image]
[image]

Please let me know how to hookup these together.

Please give me a circuit for this type of assembly with Arduino code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make a google search;
[image: Wiring instructions]

Here is some code to get you started

```
// Declaration of variables
#define Step 7     // Pin that transmits the "step" order to the board
#define Dir  6     // Pin that indicates the direction of the rotation
int vit  =   10 ;   // Speed of the rotation (smaller means faster rotation)
int sens =   1  ;  // Rotation direction (0 or 1)


void setup()
{
  pinMode( Step  , OUTPUT );
  pinMode( Dir   , OUTPUT );
}
void loop()
{
    digitalWrite( Dir   , sens);
    digitalWrite( Step  , LOW);
    // Fabrication d'un "Pas"
    digitalWrite( Step, HIGH );
    delay(vit);
    digitalWrite( Step, LOW );
    delay(vit);
}
```

Just a google search and I got on [this site][2] which had the code I gave you.
I think you can also find some libraries that can do the work for you.

in case that you need to wait less than a millisecond, `millis()` won't be useful for you; instead, use `delayMicroseconds()` which will make you wait a thousandth (at minimum) of a millisecond.

**EDIT**

For what you asked you have to first get the voltage:

```
float voltage = analogRead ( 0 )  * (3.0 / 1023.0);
```

You just have to adapt your speed relatively to the voltage.
To do this, I suggest you the [map function](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/map) directly from Arduino site.

Be careful just because whatever you are doing, analogRead takes **100 microseconds** to get the voltage, so if you need to go very fast you can't.  I suggest you to work with a different type of communication, like Serial, SPI or I2c.

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me how can i control motor speed/RPM using a analog voltage which came from some other device. The voltage are range in 0-3V.

Comment: There you go. I edited the answer for your question