# I2C or SPI to control 6 motors?

Tags: pins, motor, i2c, spi

<sup>I am a hobbyist & know little about electronics.</sup>

I am making a robot arm, like [this one](http://www.lynxmotion.com/c-124-al5a.aspx). For which I will need 2 stepper motors (for elbow & shoulder joint) & 4 simple DC motors.

Which means I will need to allocate a lot of pins on my board (Uno).

So I was just reading about I2C & then eventually SPI. My question is:

1. Is it possible to control 6 motors (or atleast 2 steppers) with I2C or SPI (assuming the motors are powered by seperate source), if so can you point me to someone's example code.
2. If not possible, how do I overcome the shortage of pins, because I have already dedicated them to many sensors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the stepper motors, the easiest way to work with them is by using a very common [A4988 board](https://www.pololu.com/product/1182) which is widely used with 3D printers. The controls are very easy and for them I send you [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/stepper-motor-controller-using-leonardo-pro-micro/8977#8977) which I answered some time ago.

Then, you say that you haven't got a lot of connections left on your UNO board, so I think that SPI would't be very useful, as it takes 3 pins for the data transmission (SCLK, MOSI, MISO) plus one pin for every device you connect.

The best way (even if it is a little slower that SPI) is to use I2C, which needs that you leave unused analog input pins A4 and A5, as they are the I2C BUS. Unfortunately I haven't any knowledge about I2C DC motor drivers.

For the steppers, I suggest to take a look at [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Serial-I2C-Microstepping-Motor-Driver-DC-PWM-CNC-Raspberry-Pi-Aduino-1-2A-/111177026930), but it depends by your budget for what you can buy.

You could fix the pin shortage problem by adding some [74HC595](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf) shift registers. They aren't very expensive (less than a dollar, or if you live in europe, .5€) and they can be daisy-chained. To control them, see the [Arduino website tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/tutorial/ShiftOut).

Finally, if the pins that you use are inputs, use a [74HC165](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT165.pdf), which is the opposite of a 595. As always, see the [Arduino website tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/tutorial/ShiftIn).